# Can I play on on multiple servers without affecting my existing characters from a single account?

Tags: diablo-iii

I regularly game with different groups and while I have played exclusively on the US servers to this point I have some interest in gaming with friends in Europe on the EU server.

We've seen that you can use a US activated copy of Diablo to access the EU server and it's clear that I will not be able to access my current characters on the EU server but my question is "If I log into the EU server and start creating characters there, will I in any way harm/affect my current US characters?"

IE Does Blizzard require you to commit to a single server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have characters on both the EU server and the US one, I can assure you they are completely separate, there is no way to even detect that I have characters on one server when I'm logged in on the other. The auction house is separate as well, so there is no way to share items either. Both servers are completely isolated from each other.

Answer (score 0):

As far I know it doesn't effect. All regions are completely separate and everything associated with a character in a region stays in that *region only*

This is what I found in their [forums](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5149176113)

> ```
> You don't. The 3 regions are completely separate.
> ```
>
> Global Play means you can play on them, but everything stays in its
>   associated region.

Comment: Of course the question you link to asks about moving characters to the new servers, something I specifically said I knew I couldn't do.

Comment: @Stephen - The linked question still answers your question.  A Diablo III license gives you the right to access ANY of the Diablo III regions.   **Each region is seperate.**  So characters on EU region will not effect characters on the NA region they can't they are seperate.